# NHibernate Projections - how to project collections

Tags: nhibernate

Have a scenario where I need to only select a single/few columns from an entity, but multiple children in a query. 
I have been trying with projections but getting an error on the collections property. This is such a normal situation, yet cannot find info on projecting collections - only properties.

```
Customer customerAlias = null;
Order orderAlias = null;
 var list = _session.QueryOver<Customer>(() => customerAlias)
                    .JoinAlias(x => x.Orders, () => orderAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                    .Select(
                       Projections.Property(() => customerAlias.Name),
                       Projections.Property(() => customerAlias.Orders))//this is the issue
                   .List<object>();
```

Error returned is:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate QueryOver projections - projecting collections to DTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535961/nhibernate-queryover-projections-projecting-collections-to-dto)

Comment: please do not repeat questions...

Comment: You've selected two properties, maybe .List<object[]>()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot be done in NH 3.3. https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3176

Answer (score 2):

How about reversing the query (assuming that Order has a Customer property):

```
var list = _session.QueryOver<Order>()
                .Select(
                   Projections.Property(o => o.Customer.Name),
                   Projections.Property(o => o.OrderProperty1),
                   Projections.Property(o => o.OrderProperty2)) // etc..
               .List<object[]>();
```